# Passing values between PHP Functions

Tags: php

Say I have the following function:

```
public static function checkRunin($fieldPickup) {
    // CODE

    return self::getFare();
}
```

and I want to pass `$fieldPickup` to the `getFare()` function below:

```
private static function getFare($int_terminate) {
    // CODE
}
```

but the `getFare()` already has a function passed to it via an AJAX request, so you can't pass as like `return self::getFare($fieldPickup);`

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Okay...huh? Sorry, I don't get what you want. Is it a big problem giving it a different function name?

Comment: basically I want to use $fieldPickup within the getFare function, but I can't pass it using `return self::getFare($fieldPickup);` so I was wondering how you would do this?

Comment: and I can't pass it like return self::getFare($int_terminate,$fieldPickup); because $int_terminate comes from a different function

Comment: declare some variables for your class that hold stuff like int_terminate in it and then you can call them within your function using $this->variable rather than passing the variables into the function.  set them on construct of class ?

Comment: define $fieldPickup as global variable

Answer (score 0):

use only this

```
return self::getFare($fieldPickup);
```

Comment: I get the following:-

Invocation parameter types are not compatible with declared (in PHP Storm)

Answer (score 0):

Either you define `$fieldPickup` as a [static class variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), either like Yogesh suggested, you pass `$fieldPickup` as parameter to method `getFare()`.

Comment: You have plenty of examples on the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php